# I have a problem programming with unity to paste the image of footsteps on the ground when the player moves

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public class FootPaint : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region --- helpers --
    public enum enumFoot
    {
        Left,
        Right,
    }
    #endregion

    public GameObject LeftPrefab;
    public GameObject RightPrefab;
    public float FootprintSpacer = 1.0f;
    private Vector3 LastFootprint;
    private enumFoot WhichFoot;
    public GameObject[] intdexPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        LastFootprint = this.transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        FootPaints();

    }
    public void FootPaints()
    {
        if (CheckPaintItem.instance.isPaint == true && gameObject.name == "PlayerSeek")
        {
            float DistanceSinceLastFootprint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, LastFootprint);
            if (DistanceSinceLastFootprint >= FootprintSpacer)
            {
                LastFootprint = this.transform.position;
                if (WhichFoot == enumFoot.Left)
                {
                    SpawnFootDecal(LeftPrefab);
                    WhichFoot = enumFoot.Right;
                }
                else if (WhichFoot == enumFoot.Right)
                {
                    SpawnFootDecal(RightPrefab);
                    WhichFoot = enumFoot.Left;
                }
                LastFootprint = new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y + 1f, this.transform.position.z);
            }
        }
      


    }

    public void SpawnFootDecal(GameObject prefab)
    {

        int index = Random.Range(0, intdexPos.Length);
        //where the ray hits the ground we will place a footprint

        GameObject decal = Instantiate(prefab);

        decal.transform.position = intdexPos[index].transform.position;
        
        decal.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, intdexPos[index].transform.eulerAngles.y);
        //turn the footprint to match the direction the player is facing


    }
}



public class CheckPaintItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static CheckPaintItem instance;
    #region boolPaint
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isPaint = false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isPaintYellow = false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isPaintRed = false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isPaintBlue = false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isPaintGreen = false;
    #endregion
    private float currentMoveSpeed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        currentMoveSpeed = 2.5f;
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
       
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "PaintsYellow")
        {
            Debug.Log("Yellow");
            isPaint = true;
            isPaintYellow = true;
            StartCoroutine(timePaint());
        }
       else if (other.gameObject.tag == "PaintsRed")
        {
            isPaint = true;
            isPaintRed = true;
            StartCoroutine(timePaint());
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.tag == "PaintsBlue")
        {
            isPaint = true;
            isPaintBlue = true;
            StartCoroutine(timePaint());
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.tag == "PaintsGreen")
        {
            isPaint = true;
            isPaintGreen = true;
            StartCoroutine(timePaint());
        }
        else
        {
            isPaint = false;
            isPaintYellow = false;
            isPaintRed = false;
            isPaintBlue = false;
            isPaintGreen = false;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "PaintsGlue")
        {

            StartCoroutine(changeMoveSpeedSlow());

        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Speed")
        {

            StartCoroutine(changeMoveSpeedFast());
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

        }

    }


    IEnumerator changeMoveSpeedSlow()
    {
        PlayerController.instance._moveSpeed = PlayerController.instance._moveSpeed / 2 + 0.2f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        PlayerController.instance._moveSpeed = currentMoveSpeed;
    }


    IEnumerator changeMoveSpeedFast()
    {
        PlayerController.instance._moveSpeed = PlayerController.instance._moveSpeed + 1f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        PlayerController.instance._moveSpeed = currentMoveSpeed;
    }

    IEnumerator timePaint()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(15f);
        isPaint = false;
    }
}
```

I want to code the game "hide and seek", but I had a problem when the character stepped into a puddle of paint.

My game has 1 character finding and 5 moving AIs, I want whether the AI or the player steps into the puddle, it will leave footprints. But I have problem with above scripts tag, I add script tag with all characters.

So one character walks in, all the other characters show their footsteps. I don't know if my direction is correct. If anyone wants to understand more about the game I'm coding, you can go to youtube and type hide and seek and it will come out.

Thank you.

Comment: I hope someone can help me with this problem. The character Seek walks into a puddle of paint and all other characters show that painted paw. I just want someone to come in, only that person will have painted feet. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that the problem lies within `CheckPaintItem.instance.isPaint`. I don't know what that script is exactly, but it's probably a singleton pattern as there is an instance call. If that's the case, then you're checking if any CheckPaintItem is true globally as it's fields are pretty much static. So make changes to CheckPaintItem or show us what it does exactly.

Comment: script tag checkpaintItem, I use to check for collision when the object enters the puddle. I have the script checkpaint item assigned above. please help me find the problem with

Comment: Do you know how static fields and singletons work? Your CheckPaintItem script is being accessed via singleton pattern and your isPaint variable behaves like a static field - therefore when ANY of your players/AI touches paint, it changes globally (for everyone). Easiest solutions is to access regular script assigned to each GameObject and not via instance. So instead of `CheckPaintItem.instance.isPaint` try `GetComponent<CheckPaintItem>().isPaint`.